lmfit: constrain the sigma of multiple gaussian profiles to be the same
I am fitting multiple gaussian peaks to a spectrum. I would like to constrain the gaussian peaks to all have the same value of sigma. I am using lmfit and have written the following example code to illustrate my problem:
#generating fake spectrum
x = linspace(-20, 20, 101)
g1 = gaussian(x, 2.33, 0.21, 1.51)
g2 = gaussian(x, 2.33, 10, 5)
g3 = gaussian(x, 2.33, -8, 0.5)
y=g1+g2+g3

#model
gauss_1=GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars= gauss_1.make_params(amplitude=2,center=0.21,sigma=1)

gauss_2=GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars.update(gauss_2.make_params(amplitude=2,center=10,sigma=1))

gauss_3=GaussianModel(prefix='g3_')
pars.update(gauss_3.make_params(amplitude=2,center=-8,sigma=1))

pars['g1_sigma'].set(expr='g2_sigma')
pars['g2_sigma'].set(expr='g3_sigma')

mod=gauss_1+gauss_2+gauss_3


Is it possible to combine:
pars['g1_sigma'].set(expr='g2_sigma')
pars['g1_sigma'].set(expr='g3_sigma') 

into a single line? In reality I have multiple gaussian peaks (~15) and it would be quite repetitive to write this out multiple times.
Or is there a better way to constrain all the gaussian peaks to have the same sigma?
